# Proxy decrypt algorithm in Extended Proxy-Assisted Attribute Based Encryption (ABE) Scheme

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation, abe

**Context**

I'm trying to implement the Attribute-Based Encryption (ABE) scheme described in the paper - *[Extended Proxy-Assisted Approach: Achieving Revocable Fine-Grained Encryption of Cloud Data (Yang et al.)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-24177-7_8)*.

To summarize the scheme in my own words - it is a CP-ABE scheme where decryption of a ciphertext `c` is performed in 2 stages - firstly, at the cloud server using the cloud server's `CS` secret key `skcs` together with a user-specific attribute-based proxy key `pxku` - and secondly, on the user's machine using their secret key `sku`.

The first stage is performed by the proxy decrypt algorithm `PxDec`. From the paper:

> `PxDec(skcs , pxku , c) → v`: The proxy decryption algorithm takes as input
>   CS’s private key, skcs , a user’s proxy key, pxku , and a ciphertext, c, and
>   outputs an intermediate value, v.
>   The CS runs this algorithm to help a user, u, partially decrypt an encrypted
>   record requested by the user with the corresponding proxy key.

**Problem**

The paper goes on to describe the construction of the `PxDec()` algorithm and that is where I'm struggling with my understanding.

I've highlighted the problem section in the below excerpt, from the paper:

> [image: construction of PxDec]

**Question**

Considering `DecNd()` operates on each node in the policy tree, 
one by one, what is the meaning of the set S and from where does it originate?

Then, what exactly does the `(0)` part mean in 
$\Delta_{i,S}(0)$ ?

Lastly, how does the recursive sub-routine `DecNd()` differentiate between ANDs and ORs in the policy tree?

(*It may help to know that my background is in software engineering rather than cryptography or mathematics.*)

Comment: Your first question is completely off topic here and is way too broad. Please edit your question to make it on topic; I'll have to put it on hold for now.

Comment: @Maarten thanks for your feedback. I've tried to constrain the question. Please let me know if I can improve it further...